# MySQL WITH RECURSIVE CTE: sorting by votes/likes while retaining hierarchy

Tags: mysql, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm building a forum that support nested comments like Reddit.

- Unlimited reply nesting levels
- Order comments by likes/votes where the comment with higher voteCount appears at the top, but the tree structure is retained (parent is always shown directly above children)

Basically, what I need was answered here: [Postgres WITH RECURSIVE CTE: sorting/ordering children by popularity while retaining tree structure (parents always above children)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42234230/705309). **But I need a solution that works with MySQL**

This is what I've tried so far without success:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `voteCount` int DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ios_community.comment (id,parent,content,voteCount) VALUES
     (1, NULL,'Comment 1'      ,0),
     (2, NULL,'Comment 2'      ,0),
     (3, 2   ,'Comment 2.1'    ,0),
     (4, 2   ,'Comment 2.2'    ,20),
     (5, NULL,'Comment 3'      ,5),
     (6, 3   ,'Comment 2.1.1'  ,0),
     (7, 6   ,'Comment 2.1.1.1',0);

WITH RECURSIVE nested_comments(
id,
content,
voteCount,
path,
level,
sortable
) AS (
SELECT
    id,
    content,
    voteCount,
    CAST(id AS CHAR(1000)),
    0,
    CONCAT('-', CAST(COALESCE(voteCount, 0) AS CHAR(1000)), '.', CAST(id AS CHAR(1000)))
FROM
    comment
WHERE
    parent IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.content,
    c.voteCount,
    CONCAT(nc.path, '.', CAST(c.id AS CHAR(1000))),
    nc.level + 1,
    CONCAT(nc.sortable, '.-', CAST(COALESCE(c.voteCount, 0) AS CHAR(4)), '.', CAST(c.id AS CHAR(1000)))
FROM
    nested_comments nc
JOIN comment c ON
    nc.id = c.parent
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    nested_comments
ORDER BY
    sortable;
```

#### My results

```sql
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| id | content         | voteCount | path    | level | sortable            |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 1  | Comment 1       | 0         | 1       | 0     | -0.1                |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 2  | Comment 2       | 0         | 2       | 0     | -0.2                |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 3  | Comment 2.1     | 0         | 2.3     | 1     | -0.2.-0.3           |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 6  | Comment 2.1.1   | 0         | 2.3.6   | 2     | -0.2.-0.3.-0.6      |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 7  | Comment 2.1.1.1 | 0         | 2.3.6.7 | 3     | -0.2.-0.3.-0.6.-0.7 |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 4  | Comment 2.2     | 20        | 2.4     | 1     | -0.2.-20.4          |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 5  | Comment 3       | 5         | 5       | 0     | -5.5                |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

#### The results I need

```sql
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| id | content         | voteCount | path    | level | sortable            |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 5  | Comment 3       | 5         | 5       | 0     | -5.5                |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 1  | Comment 1       | 0         | 1       | 0     | -0.1                |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 2  | Comment 2       | 0         | 2       | 0     | -0.2                |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 4  | Comment 2.2     | 20        | 2.4     | 1     | -0.2.-20.4          |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 3  | Comment 2.1     | 0         | 2.3     | 1     | -0.2.-0.3           |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 6  | Comment 2.1.1   | 0         | 2.3.6   | 2     | -0.2.-0.3.-0.6      |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| 7  | Comment 2.1.1.1 | 0         | 2.3.6.7 | 3     | -0.2.-0.3.-0.6.-0.7 |
+----+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea - build fully qualified path for each node and order by it.

The task needs in mixing descending ordering (by vote) with ascending one (by id). So one of these ordering must be reversed for to achieve one solid ordering criteria.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS (
  SELECT LENGTH(MAX(id)) nlen,  LENGTH(MAX(voteCount)) vlen,
         POW(10, LENGTH(MAX(voteCount))) - 1 vmax
  FROM comment
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT id,parent,content,voteCount,
         CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', vmax - LPAD(voteCount, vlen, 0), LPAD(id, nlen, 0)) AS CHAR(65535)) path
  FROM comment
  CROSS JOIN cte1
  WHERE parent IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT comment.id, comment.parent, comment.content, comment.voteCount,
         CONCAT_WS('-', cte2.path, vmax - LPAD(comment.voteCount, cte1.vlen, 0), LPAD(comment.id, cte1.nlen, 0))
  FROM comment
  JOIN cte2 ON cte2.id = comment.parent
  CROSS JOIN cte1
)
SELECT id, parent, content, voteCount
FROM cte2
ORDER BY path
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/13ZwiHRO

`cte1` calculates maximal lengths for values padding which provides correct string values ordering as numbers and maximal vote value for votes order reversing.

`cte2` performs recursive path building. The path consists from reversed `vote` value and `id` value. You may add it to the output list and look at the values.